# XCode не видит мой класс для обозначения таблицы в CoreData

Tags: swift

Я создал таблицу Diary. Так же создалось два файла Diary.swift и Diary+CoreDataProperties.swift

В первом просто обозначение класса:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


@objc(Diary)

class Diary: NSManagedObject {

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass


}
```

Во втором - обозначение полей:
     import Foundation
import CoreData

```
extension Diary {

@NSManaged var activity: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var activityDescription: String?
@NSManaged var alcohol: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var alcoholDescription: String?
@NSManaged var basalInsulin: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var bolusInsulin: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var carbs: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var carbsDescription: String?
@NSManaged var diaryID: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var extID: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var glucoseLevel: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var note: String?
@NSManaged var remindUtcDateTime: NSDate?
@NSManaged var sectionIdentifier: String?
@NSManaged var signs: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var synced: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var time: String?
@NSManaged var utcDateTime: String?
@NSManaged var valid: NSNumber?

}
```

Но когда я пытаюсь создать объект этого класса, он пишет мне ошибку:

> CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'Diary' for entity 'Diary'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

На английских сайтах прочитал, что перед обозначением класса Diary надо ставить

```
  @objc(Diary)
```

> CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Diary'

А если я пытаюсь определить, к примеру, activity, то он пишет

> [Diary setActivity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fed187ccb60
>   2015-11-03 16:43:31.143 journal[29592:767498] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Diary setActivity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fed187ccb60'

Читал ещё что надо в файле .xcdatamodeld указывать не просто класс Diary для таблицы, а целиком значение (journal.Diary), но XCode у меня автоматически убирает точку и это не помогает.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613971/coredata-warning-unable-to-load-class-named

Comment: и почему все методы в extension? чего не в самом классе?